# Left join on a table with condition on others table

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

I'm trying to left join multiple tables and having a clause on the third table when joining the second. I have tried with where clauses but it applies to the whole result when i just want to nullify the columns from the second table.

Let put an example it will be clearer.
I have 4 tables :

```
CREATE TABLE A (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE B (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, A_ID INTEGER, C_ID INTEGER, D_ID INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE C (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, CONDITIONS INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE D (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, CONDITIONS INTEGER);
```

The table B joining table A to tables C and D.

A sample data will be:

```
INSERT INTO A VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO A VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO A VALUES (3);

INSERT INTO C VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO C VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO C VALUES (3, 0);

INSERT INTO D VALUES (1, 0);
INSERT INTO D VALUES (2, 0);

INSERT INTO B VALUES (1, 1, 1, NULL);
INSERT INTO B VALUES (2, 1, 2, NULL);
INSERT INTO B VALUES (3, 1, 3, NULL);
INSERT INTO B VALUES (4, 2, NULL, 1);
INSERT INTO B VALUES (5, 2, NULL, 2);
```

The direct left join:

```
SELECT A.ID, B.ID, C.ID, D.ID 
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B ON B.A_ID = A.ID 
LEFT JOIN C ON B.C_ID = C.ID 
LEFT JOIN D ON B.D_ID = D.ID;
```

returns the data:

```
╔══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╗
║ A.id ║ B.id ║ C.id ║ D.id ║
╠══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
║   1  ║   1  ║   1  ║ null ║
║   1  ║   2  ║   2  ║ null ║
║   1  ║   3  ║   3  ║ null ║
║   2  ║   4  ║ null ║   1  ║
║   2  ║   5  ║ null ║   2  ║
║   3  ║ null ║ null ║ null ║
╚══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╝
```

What I'm trying to do is to filter the B table with the data from the C and D tables.
If I simply add a where condition on the request:

```
SELECT A.ID, B.ID, C.ID, D.ID 
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B ON B.A_ID = A.ID 
LEFT JOIN C ON B.C_ID = C.ID 
LEFT JOIN D ON B.D_ID = D.ID 
WHERE (C.ID IS NULL OR C.CONDITIONS = 1)
AND (D.ID IS NULL OR D.CONDITIONS = 1);
```

It returns:

```
╔══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╗
║ A.id ║ B.id ║ C.id ║ D.id ║
╠══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
║   1  ║   1  ║   1  ║ null ║
║   1  ║   2  ║   2  ║ null ║
║   3  ║ null ║ null ║ null ║
╚══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╝
```

Which it's logic but not what I want. What I want is:

```
╔══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╗
║ A.id ║ B.id ║ C.id ║ D.id ║
╠══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
║   1  ║   1  ║   1  ║ null ║
║   1  ║   2  ║   2  ║ null ║
║   2  ║ null ║ null ║ null ║
║   3  ║ null ║ null ║ null ║
╚══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╝
```

Which keeps a row with the `A.ID = 2` but finds no value in B with the matching condition from C and D.

I tried to put the conditions in the `ON` clause joining the C and D tables but it keep the data from B:

```
╔══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╗
║ A.id ║ B.id ║ C.id ║ D.id ║
╠══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
║   1  ║   1  ║   1  ║ null ║
║   1  ║   2  ║   2  ║ null ║
║   1  ║   3  ║ null ║ null ║
║   2  ║   4  ║ null ║ null ║
║   2  ║   5  ║ null ║ null ║
║   3  ║ null ║ null ║ null ║
╚══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╝
```

I am now out of ideas to do the trick.

Comment: Can you try moving your conditions from where into the join part?

Comment: I.e. from WHERE to ON.

Comment: @jarlh That's what I ment, thank you

Comment: @Veljko89, why not give that as an answer?

Comment: Well formatted question.

Comment: @Veljko89 I did it as I mentioned in the post but it keeps the data from B (with null values from C and D), what I want is if no data match joining B to C or D having the B column null.

Comment: Incidentally, I get no rows selected from your second query, as there are no rows in D that have `conditions=1`. Everything else makes sense so don't think it's a big deal.

Comment: @AlexPoole You're right I missed the `OR D.ID IS NULL` part in the request, I edit my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is the left outer joins from the `b` table to the `c` and `d` tables first, and then outer join that back to the `a` table if a value exists in either the `c` or `d` conditions columns. Like so:

```
SELECT a.id a_id, b2.b_id, b2.c_id, b2.d_id
FROM   a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT b.id b_id,
                               b.a_id,
                               c.id c_id,
                               d.id d_id
                        FROM   b
                               LEFT OUTER JOIN c ON b.c_id = c.id AND c.conditions = 1
                               LEFT OUTER JOIN d ON b.d_id = d.id AND d.conditions = 1) b2
         ON a.id = b2.a_id AND COALESCE(b2.c_id, b2.d_id) IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY a.id, b2.b_id, b2.c_id, b2.d_id;

      A_ID       B_ID       C_ID       D_ID
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          1 
         1          2          2 
         2                       
         3
```

(Thanks to Alex Poole for spotting the issues with my edited output!)

---

ETA:

This could also be written as:

```
SELECT a.id a_id, b.id b_id, c.id c_id, d.id d_id
FROM   a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (b
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN c ON b.c_id = c.id AND c.conditions = 1
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN d ON b.d_id = d.id AND d.conditions = 1)
         ON a.id = b.a_id AND COALESCE(c.id, d.id) IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY a.id, b.id, b.c_id, b.d_id;
```

which is simpler but potentially harder to decipher the intent (and therefore harder to maintain in the future). I've added it here as I had no idea this was valid syntax, and you may feel it works better for you.

Comment: This solution seems to answer the question, but what is this syntax with "subquery" without select ?

Comment: The parentheses in the joins are there to override the default join precedence - as per [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#i2080416).

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding another answer, because I really did remove the previous one as being incorrect.  I think this is the correct logic:

```
SELECT A.ID, B.ID, C.ID, D.ID 
FROM A LEFT JOIN
     (B LEFT JOIN
      C
      ON B.C_ID = C.ID AND C.CONDITIONS = 1 LEFT JOIN
      D
      ON B.D_ID = D.ID AND D.CONDITIONS = 1
     )
     ON B.A_ID = A.ID AND
        (C.ID IS NOT NULL OR D.ID IS NOT NULL);
```

This does return the correct results when I test it.

It is an interesting problem.  The idea is to use parentheses to "delay" the comparison between `A` and `B`.  This allows the condition to also determine if there is a match on `C` or `D`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found another way to do it with a subquery in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT A.ID, B.ID, C.ID, D.ID 
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B ON B.A_ID = A.ID 
    AND (B.C_ID IS NULL OR B.ID IN (SELECT B.ID FROM B JOIN C ON C.ID = B.C_ID AND C.CONDITIONS = 1)
    AND (B.D_ID IS NULL OR B.ID IN (SELECT B.ID FROM B JOIN D ON D.ID = B.D_ID AND D.CONDITIONS = 1)
LEFT JOIN C ON B.C_ID = C.ID 
LEFT JOIN D ON B.D_ID = D.ID;
```

I don't know whiwh solution will perform better having an other clause on the A table and big B, C and D tables.